# Have a fixed nav-bar but still keep scrolling active

Tags: html, css

My issue here is that I have my nav-bar set to fixed, so it follows the window and sits at the top of the page wherever they are, but when the page width is decreased the rest of the navbar items get cut off and I can't scroll to see the rest of the items. I already have a min-width set so it stops at a certain point. So when the page width is decreased I want user to be able to be able to scroll around the page and be able to see the rest of the nav-bar, not just the part that fits the page. Here's what I mean (Watch the nav-bar): http://gyazo.com/513ad98520c9821c1de640b8c1d28fdd

Do you see how I'm unable to scroll to see the rest of the navbar items when width is decreased? When I don't have the nav-bar set to fixed, it works just fine (But I need it to follow the top of the page, as to why It's fixed).

Here's some of my navbar CSS:

```
nav{
  min-width: 900px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color:white;
  width: 100%;
}

nav img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav li{
    font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 50px 0px 10px;
}
nav a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

And here's the full webpage (Yes, I know I need to make the images smaller.)
http://cydronixweb.kkhorram.info/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix:

Add `min-width: 100%;` to `body`

That just ensures you don't get weird scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly hypothetically speaking you first start with a media query . something like :

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }
```

now inside the media query you change some styles like :

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

since you've tagged the question only HTML and CSS .

[here's](http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/) the best resource on the web to create a CSS only , fully responsive menu.

Thank you.

Alexander .